# What's Wrong? Number Of Words In a Sentence Java

Tags: java, numbers, words

```
int numOfWords = str.length() - str.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Why does that not work? If str is equal to "Hello bye", numOfWords should equal 2, but when ran numOfWords equals 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use replaceAll instead of replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only replacing one blank, so the output will be `1` (at least this is what is produce in my JVM)

If you want to know the number of words then either add 1 to this number or use

```
str.split(" ").length;
```

Comment: Your split method only printed 1, not 2... Not sure why.

Comment: In that case your data is not `Hello bye`.  Are you maybe using some other charset?

Comment: I checked, and I'm sure I'm using `Hello bye`. And I have never changed from the default charset.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I was taking user input, and I was using `str = scan.next();`, but I just decided changing it to `str = scan.nextLine();` and it worked. Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use :

```
int numOfWords = str.split(" ").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope out put is much clear

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello bye";
        System.out.println("Length of Input String = " + str.length() + " for String = " + str);
        System.out.println("Length of Input String with space removed = " + str.replace(" ", "").length() + " for String = "
                + str.replace(" ", ""));
        int numOfWords = str.length() - str.replace(" ", "").length();
        System.out.println(numOfWords);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Length of Input String = 9 for String = Hello bye
Length of Input String with space removed = 8 for String = Hellobye
1
```

Comment: My output shows 0, but it should be showing 1. How could my output not work like that?